# CSS filters load very slow when applied dynamically to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-filters

I'm trying to apply a grayscale filter to elements to bring them out of focus when manipulating data.

I'm just applying a class to all the relevant elements but there's a very noticeable hang when loading the CSS filter onto the elements.

Any ideas for making this faster and lag-free? I'd like to retain the grayscale effect but it's not responsive enough. I've tried this with different CSS like `opacity: 0.4;` to compare the speed and it's definitely the CSS filter that is causing the problem, not the javascript.

Here's the relevant JS/CSS

JS:

```
$("#users li").draggable({
    revert: function(socketObj) {
        if (socketObj === false) {
            // Drop was rejected, revert the helper.
            $(".fc-event").removeClass("greyscale");
            return true;
        } else {
            // Drop was accepted, don't revert.
            return false;
        }
    },
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".fc-event").each(function(index, element) {
            if(/* some condition is met */) {
                $(element).addClass("greyscale");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.greyscale {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `$(".fc-event")` is slow, if it does not change you could store that at startup and then the function would not have to search the whole DOM for these elements each time.

Comment: `$(".fc-event")` does change a lot, and I'm sure that's not the problem because when I use a different CSS effect like `opacity` like I mentioned above, it's very responsive and the effect is applied instantly.

Comment: opacity is a lot easier to hardware accelerate

Comment: I understand that but that's not the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: oh, my point was that could be why opacity is fast and grayscale is slow.

Comment: Yes, actually CSS Filters are expensive resources. Plus they are very experimental and not even IE supports them. Opacity is cheap compared to CSS Filters, that's why it runs smoothly.

Comment: For reference, the solution I went with was to manually calculate the grayscale target color and animate using jQuery to the new color. I used data attributes to store the original to allow reverting. Bit of a complicated solution, but it worked the best, with minimal lag.